# Set environment variables into azure devops pipelines step from template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Given I have following step in Azure Devops pipeline:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run tests
  inputs:
    command: "test"
    env:
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "test"
      "Case_sensitive_environment_variable_key": "This is the value"
```

I'd like to move this step into the template and enable users of that template to pass in `env` key values making sure it keeps case sensitivity of keys and values.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi there, I have updated the answer below according to the expectation. May I know if the sample works for you? Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3):

According to your description and to transfer the parameter as the environmental varailbles on the level of a task, you may try [Passing parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#passing-parameters) into the template and using the parameter type of `object`.

Kindly take the following main YAML pipeline and template.yml for a reference.

Main

```
trigger: none
parameters:
- name: pEnvironment
  type: object
  default:
    ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "TEST 1"
    Case_sensitive_environment_variable_key: "This is the value 1"
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
stages:
- stage:
  jobs:
  - template: Templates/template1.yml
    parameters:
      transferedEnv: ${{ parameters.pEnvironment }}
```

Template

```
parameters:
- name: transferedEnv
  type: object
jobs:
- job:
  steps:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Run tests
    inputs:
      command: "test"
    env:
      ${{ parameters.transferedEnv }}
```

When we run the main pipeline, we can input as well the values of the `env` to transferred into the template.

[image: Runtime parameters]

Comment: Instead of passing parameters one by one, I'd like to pass whole dictionary as the parameter to `env`. Is it possible?

Comment: @PatrikMihalčin The answer is yes, actually. I have updated the sample YAMLs for your reference. Hope they are helpful.